# Error regarding proper implementation of the interface

Tags: java

So, this program requires the user to calculate the total tuition based on the cred it hours and student status. IF US student then 700 dollars per cred hr and 400 dollar registration fee. If Intl student then 1000 dollar per cred hr and 500 dollar registration fee. And if MI student then 500 dollar per cred hr and 200 dollar registration fee

My problem with the program is that the output should be:

Jack's bill:    $ 6,700
Lucy's bill:    $10,900
Hao's bill:     $12,500

The total tuition revenue is $30,100

But, I am getting this output (I feel like the value of both name and the cred hrs is not being fetched properly):

null's bill:    $   200
null's bill:    $   400
null's bill:    $   500

The total tuition revenue is $ 1,100

**IStudent.java**

```
public interface IStudent {

    // return the name of the student;
    String getName();

    // return the number of credit hours that this student registered
    int getCreditHours();

    // calculate the tuition for this student
    int calculateTuition();
}
```

**IUniversity.java**

```
public interface IUniversity {

    // return a list of students
    ArrayList<IStudent> getStudentList();

    // return a list of students
    int calculateTotalTuition();

    // add a student to student list
    void addStudent(IStudent student);
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IUniversity mu = new University();
        IStudent  stu1 = new MichiganStudent("Jack",13);
        mu.addStudent(stu1);
        IStudent  stu2 = new USStudent("Lucy",15);
        mu.addStudent(stu2);
        IStudent  stu3 = new InternationalStudent("Hao",12);
        mu.addStudent(stu3);

        for(int i = 0; i < mu.getStudentList().size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(mu.getStudentList().get(i).getName() + 
                    "'s bill:");
            System.out.printf("\t$%,6d\n", mu.getStudentList().get(i).calculateTuition());
        }
        System.out.printf("\nThe total tuition revenue is $%,6d\n", 
                mu.calculateTotalTuitution());
    }
}
```

This is my code:

For University class:

```
public class University implements IUniversity {

    ArrayList<IStudent> mu = new ArrayList<IStudent>();

    public ArrayList<IStudent> getStudentList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mu;
    }

    public int calculateTotalTuition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int tuition = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < mu.size(); i++ ) {
            tuition = tuition + mu.get(i).calculateTuition();
        }
        return tuition;
    }

    public void addStudent(IStudent student) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mu.add(student);
    }

}
```

And one of the student class:

```
public class USStudent implements IStudent {

    public USStudent(String string, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private String name;
    private int credhrs;

    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;
    }

    public int getCreditHours() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return credhrs;
    }

    public int calculateTuition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int total = 0;
        total = total + 400 + (700 * credhrs);
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't set value at parameterized contructor at concrete classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to store the values into the instance variables.

```
public USStudent(String string, int i) {
    this.name = string;
    this.credhrs = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provide no explicit initialization to instance variables, they will be initialized to the default initial values, based on the data type of the variable. This is the default JVM behavior.

In your snippet, what JVM did it as mentioned below:

```
private String name = null;
private int credhrs=0;
```

As you are using parameterized constructor and your intention is to use the value passed along with object. So, lnitialize the private variables in the constructor it will solve this problem.

example mentioned by user7 same as above.